# random number from list based off percentage

Tags: java, random

I have a list of numbers and I need to pull from that list a random number, but I need to make sure that after pulling out a set amount of numbers from said list, that they will form to a pre-defined percentile for each set out of the output numbers.

Example in coded form:

```
int[] nums = {2,3,6};

int twoPer = 25;
int threePer = 45;
int sixPer = 30;
```

So in this example if I pulled out 100 numbers at random I would need to have 25 2's, 45 3's and 30 6's.

Comment: If you have a predefined percentile rather than probabilities for the numbers, it doesn't sound like they will be random choices. Are you pulling the numbers one by one or x amount at once? And are you putting the numbers back after pulling or not?

Comment: Its unclear (even your example code) what you are trying to say. Can you give another example?

Comment: This isn't random, it's defined. If you wanted to sample probabilistically then you could use random. Otherwise you need to create a collection with the correct proportions and shuffle it.

Comment: The idea for the code I need is that when given a set of number it will chose one at random as output, and add it to a array of ints for later use, but when that array is full in needs to be able to be broken down using the percentages that were set for each number, so if my array was my terrain and 2 was a dirt tile: I need 25% of my terrain to be dirt, but scattered around randomly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use something like weighted random generation (Biased):

```
int[] nums = {2,3,6};
int[] numweights = {25, 45, 30}; //weight of each element above
int totalweight = 100;

public int SetRandom() {

    int[] weighednums = new int[totalweight]; //new array to hold "weighted" nums
    int currentfruit = 0;
    int place = 0;
    while (currentfruit < nums.length) { //step through each num[] element
        for (int i=0; i < numweights[currentfruit]; i++){
            weighednums[place] = nums[currentfruit];
            place++;
        }
        currentfruit++;
    }

    int randomnumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * totalweight);
    System.out.println(weighednums[randomnumber] + " at " + randomnumber);
    return weighednums[randomnumber];
}
```

Comment: I just tried to use that code snip-it you posted and it throws a out of bounds exception at: weighednums[weighednums.length] = nums[currentfruit];
any idea's on a quick fix, cause I can not confirm if this is the solution to my problem

Comment: @34638a fixed the small issue, it has to be `weighednums[i] = nums[currentnum];`

Comment: this seams to work fairly ok, my only problem with it is that it sometimes spits out a 0 value, any idea's as to why that would be?

Comment: @34638a You might need to print the `weightednums` and check that

Comment: @nash_ag:  You forgot to adjust the indexes in `weighednums`; you are overwriting the original start of the array for each weight ...

Comment: this should work fine thanks, I'll answer with the edited code complete for plug and play in java;

Comment: I am unable to accept the code I posted below can you copy it over your code so I can accept it thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Answer complete with revisions for Java:

```
int[] nums = {2,3,6};
int[] numweights = {25, 45, 30}; //weight of each element above
int totalweight = 100;

public int SetRandom() {

    int[] weighednums = new int[totalweight]; //new array to hold "weighted" nums
    int currentfruit = 0;
    int place = 0;
    while (currentfruit < nums.length) { //step through each num[] element
        for (int i=0; i < numweights[currentfruit]; i++){
            weighednums[place] = nums[currentfruit];
            place++;
        }
        currentfruit++;
    }

    int randomnumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * totalweight);
    System.out.println(weighednums[randomnumber] + " at " + randomnumber);
    return weighednums[randomnumber];
}
```